# Edição de uma resposta pelo OP

Tags: debate

Encontrei uma situação relacionado a edição de uma resposta pelo OP e fiquei com dúvida sobre como proceder.

A resposta em questão é a seguinte: [Organização de projetos em pacotes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26065/organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-projetos-em-pacotes/26066#26066)

Existe uma edição sugerida pendente aprovação onde o OP informa que o código da resposta está errado, inserindo na resposta o retorno do erro.

Entendo que essa edição deve ser rejeita. Como devemos proceder nesses casos?

Comment: Acho que **a comunidade agiu de forma correta ao rejeitar a edição**. E o fato dele ter escrito sobre `sdks` no lugar de IDE me confundiu e por isso minha resposta foi em função da visibilidade dos construtores e não do classpath que era o *problema* do usuário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apenas trazendo a público qual era a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14936) do OP:

> O erro persiste:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Leandro\Documents\Java\Exercícios\testes\pacotes>javac Teste.java
> Teste.java:3: error: package pacotes.objeto does not exist
> import pacotes.objeto.Texto;
>                  ^
> Teste.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>     Texto t = new Texto();
>     ^
> symbol:   class Texto
> location: class Teste
> Teste.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
>     Texto t = new Texto();
>                   ^
> symbol:   class Texto
> location: class Teste
> 3 errors
> ```

Isso é uma tentativa de debater a postagem e isso deve (e foi) corretamente rejeitado.

O OP quis argumentar algo, e ele deveria ter feito isso resumidamente através de um comentário ou editar a própria pergunta dele mostrando o erro que ele encontrou ao tentar uma solução X. Isso é perfeitamente plausível.

A edição em publicações que não são de sua autoria devem se limitar a corrigir coisas que não alteram o sentido original da publicação, como por exemplo remover saudações, formatar adequadamente o código, consertar erros de português ou de digitação e coisas do tipo. De maneira alguma deve-se editar uma publicação alheia para conversar, debater ou argumentar.